# Connection killed Azure container

Tags: python, azure, containers, blob

I am trying to access to a Azure container to dowload some blobs with my python code.
My code is working perfectly on windows but when I execute it on my debian VM I have this error message :

```
<azure.storage.blob._container_client.ContainerClient object at 0x7f0c51cafd10>
Killed
admin_bbt@vm-bbt-cegidToAZ:/lsbCodePythonCegidToAZ/fuzeo_bbt_vmLinux_csvToAZ$
```

The blob I am trying to acces is not mine but I do have the sas key.
My code fail after this line :

```
container = ContainerClient.from_container_url(sas_url)
```

What I have tried to do :

- move my VM to an other location
- open the port 445 on my VM
- install cifs-utils

Answer (score 0):

Usually this issue comes when our VM was not enabled for managed identities for azure resources on VM. This MS Docs helped me to enable it successfully ([MSDocs1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-managed-identity), [MSDocs2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/qs-configure-portal-windows-vm))

We need to check for network access rules which are as below

1. Go to the storage account you want to secure.
2. Select on the settings menu called  **Networking**.
3. To deny access by default, choose to allow access from  **Selected networks**. To allow traffic from all networks, choose to allow access from  **All networks**.
4. Select  **Save**  to apply your changes.

Also along with these setting changes, need to ensure users can access blob storage, and might need to add vnet integration
Check this [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal) for understanding about Azure Storage firewall rules.

We can use [MSI](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/resource-manager-python-manage-resources-with-msi) to authenticate with VM

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The problem is that I don"t have access to the storage account as it is not mine. According to the links you send I have turned on the identity Status of the VM. I also have oponed all the port. I've launch the code and it worked once ! But now when I launch it again it still telling me : Killed like before